# SQL Architecture design for handling employee competencies

Tags: mysql, architecture

ninjas, I understand that this probably is a "way too broad" or "wrong portal" type question but SO feels like home, so I will give it a try anyways.

I have a table with employees

```
Table: employee
id, name
1 - John
2 - Jane
3 - Obama
4 - Donald
```

...nothing fancy. And then there is competencies table (a classifier of special tasks/responsibilieties)

```
competencies table:
id, name
1 - Janitor
2 - Sysadmin
3 - Programmer
4 - Pilot
...
```

Each employee can have multiple competencies (relations table)

table: employee_competency

```
id, employee_id, competency_id
1 - 1 - 1  - John is a Janitor
2 - 1 - 2  - John is also a Sysadmin (imagine that)
3 - 2 - 3  - Jane is a Programmer
4 - 3 - 3  - Obama is a Programmer
5 - 3 - 4  - ...and a Pilot
6 - 4 - 1  - Donald is a Janitor
```

The existencial problem of a database architecture or how to handle such cases.

1. I want to be able to define unlimited count of competencies and these competencies can vary from one customer to another (where the project I am programming will be installed - each project installation can have a different set of competencies)
2. In the code, I want to be able to select employees with specific competency (for example - list all employees who are Pilots)....

By hard-coding the competency ID when listing employees I loose ability to define competencies freely. I could define custom fields in the employee table like is_janitor, is_sysadmin, is_programmer, is_pilot, etc... but then I loose the ability to define unlimited count of competencies...

Is there a way to solve this rather XY problem with a different DB architecture approach?

Comment: I want to be able to set up the same project for multiple customers - each customer can have its own set of employee competencies.

Comment: Right i totally mist that point.. "I want to be able to set up the same project for multiple customers - each customer can have its own set of employee competencies. " you mean if you should make a database per customer or make a customer table and use customer_id's in the existing tables to "seperated" the data between the customers?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem with the current design

Comment: Yes, the design you have with three tables is a typical many-to-many design. Design your app to allow customers to pick an existing competency, or else enter a new one. When they enter a new competency, insert it to the `competency` table and fetch its auto-generated id before inserting to the `employee_competency` table.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea here is that you have to have that list that allows you to pick a competency be data-driven as well.  So, when you are on the screen/form/page where you are selecting the competency to list, you drive that selection by the table of competencies in the database, passing the ID of the competency as the Value of the selection back to your query so that you can query the list of employees by competency.

You should never put individual IDs into the system.  Now, this gets complicated when you have behavior you want to drive based on the competency.  This requires thinking at a higher level of abstraction.  For example, lets say you have a form where you want to show another tab to allow the customer to select what planes a  pilot is certified on.  To drive this, I usually create flags that actually define the driving behaviors (like CAN_SELECT_PLANES) to add to a related table.  This table defines the capabilities of the system, not the capabilities of the competency.  It is important to maintain that abstraction because customers will want to vary their competency name, and you will find new uses for that feature later on.

Comment: The way you are proposing is that I should implement some sort of service configuration file/table, that defines, for example, specific forms/reports/pages and specific table/ID relations so that the desired results are displayed? Do I understand you correctly? Are there any limitations to this approach or is it not going to become extra complicated later as the project development goes on and on? In your case CAN_SELECT_PLANES - is that a constant defined separately from the database and used to shape the results of a global SQL query ?

Answer (score 0):

To select all programmers from the database, use for example:

```
SELECT
 e.name AS empl_name,
 c.name AS comp_name
FROM 
  employee_competency ec,
  competencies c,
  employee e
WHERE
  c.id=ec.competency_id
AND
  e.id=ec.employee_id
AND
  c.id=3
```

Comment: That is the problem - I cannot specify "AND c.id=3" somewhere in the code due to the fact, that the ID 3 can be something totally different for someone else who makes the competencies table. I am looking for a more or less universal solution for such cases.

Comment: Use   "  c.name='Programmer'  "     or    "  c.name LIKE '%Pilot%'   "